# passing string value fill dropdown from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I need to fill the dropdown value from database passing string value.here i am gettin filled dataset from database but it is not binding so that i am unable to fill properly the dropdown and select items from dropdown.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string strCreatedId = string.Empty;
        strCreatedId = "2";
        fillgroupname(id_ddlgroupname,strCreatedId);
    }

}

 public void fillgroupname(DropDownList id_ddlgroupname, string strCreatedId)
{
    DataSet dsgroup = new DataSet();
    dsgroup = objUser.GetFillGroup(strCreatedId);
    if (dsgroup.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        if (dsgroup.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            this.id_ddlgroupname.DataSource = dsgroup;
            this.id_ddlgroupname.DataTextField = "c_group_name";
            this.id_ddlgroupname.DataValueField = "c_group_name";
            this.id_ddlgroupname.DataBind();
            this.id_ddlgroupname.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
        }
    }
```

I will upload image as it appears.
Image1:
[image: when the page load and i will get dropdown like this]

Image2:
[image: when i click dropdown to select values]

Image3:[image: here i am unable to select the items and it will disable the dropdown]

like this the dropdown issue i am facing i am not able to know where i am going wrong.pls help me.

Comment: did you make dropdowns AutoPostBack="True" ?

Comment: @sajanyamaha No i am not using autopostback

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
public void fillgroupname(DropDownList id_ddlgroupname, string strCreatedId)
{
DataSet dsgroup = new DataSet();
dsgroup = objUser.GetFillGroup(strCreatedId);

id_ddlgroupname.DataSource = dsgroup;
id_ddlgroupname.DataTextField = "c_group_name";
id_ddlgroupname.DataValueField = "c_group_name";
id_ddlgroupname.DataBind();
ListItem li = new ListItem("--Select--","0");
id_ddlgroupname.Items.Insert(0, li);
}
```

This is working for me, I hope it will be use full for you.

Comment: no Its not working for me.i am populating dropdown from database

Comment: Specify me some details. What is **VIEW BUTTON** do as shown in image, and how you fill data i.e. specify the details code of `objUser.GetFillGroup(strCreatedId);` it will be easy to understand your problem...

Answer (score 0):

sorry. I got solved my issue it was problem in my validation using jquery.